# Access Database throw "Disk or Network error" when running in server

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Firstly I looked up every OleDbException "Disk or network error" topics but nothing solved my problem. 
 Im developing a program for my office on Windows Forms and using access database. When I test the program in local everything is fine(db is in the local computer). But when I moved up the database into the shared folder (office server) , its starting to throw Disk or Network Error while connecting to db(not every connection).

1. I can read user table data (it means select command working)
2. But i cant read hours table data (but sth is wrong)
3. I can add new hours to table  (insert command working)
4. But i cant add a new user  (sth is wrong as well)

Connection String:

> OleDbConnection db = new
>   OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
>   Source=\Ug_Filesrv\Ug_Proje$\0140_SAU_CAE_Library\FOKS
>   Database\FOKS_Database.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456;");

[Error İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXS00.jpg)

Note: I cant change the database type , only access Database allowed.

Any help needed. Thank you.

Comment: Source is "\UG_Filesrv" sure thats not "\\UG_Filesrv" .. using access over UNCs probably isnt the best idea.

Comment: is this database shared with multiple users? If so its most likely multiple users accessing it at the same time as this is only a file on disk when you write to it it gets locked for other users.

Comment: Have you tried adding `<identity impersonate="true" username="user" password="password" />`
in your `web.config`?

Comment: 1-) yeah its \\UG ...  (miss-copy), I understand but have to use Access :(  BugFinder

Comment: 2-) yeah its shared for multiple users , and also Im the only one who is using the system for now , but thank you .  Rafal

Comment: 3-) No, I didnt add this , what does this block do ? Dungeon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!!

Have you tried adding

> `<identity impersonate="true" username="user" password="password" />`

in your web.config?  By Dungeon

Comment: You should ask OP to make it an answer